# What commands do I use and what files do I edit to configure a new nx workspace in a directory structure of existing nodejs/.NET applications?

Tags: monorepo, nomachine-nx, nx-monorepo

Background:

I've been following multiple nx [videos](https://youtu.be/Dq2ftPf3sn4) and [installation guides](https://blog.nrwl.io/adding-nx-to-an-existing-monorepo-by-running-one-command-426fa519d943) which claim to be simple with `npx add-nx-to-monorepo`. The guides then talk about editing workspace.json, which is [deprecated](https://nx.dev/deprecated/workspace-json), and that the packages.json files in (what I assume is) the current working directory and those recursively stored in child directories of the working directory will be detected.. but I'm missing something because I see nothing of the sort, nor really a guide to configuring nx.json or edit the autogenerated config files to make them do anything. And this [Project Configuration](https://nx.dev/reference/project-configuration) page has me more confused than guided on how to configure the thing.

My scenario:

I'm trying to improve build times, introduce caching and local testing to a github repository. The projects exist already and are in production. I've merged 16 github repositories into a single monorepo for testing, but i'll summarise it with just 3.

My directory structure:

```
monorepo
`- apps
  `- adminportal
    `- frontend - .NET
    `- backend  - NextJS
  `- clientportal
    `- frontend - .NET 
    `- backend  - NextJS
`- libs
  `- common-library
```

Going into monorepo/apps/adminportal/backend, typing `nx init` configures the directory correctly, I can `nx build` my project and it caches correctly, the second build taking miliseconds instead of 1-2 minutes. The same with clientportal/backend.

Where I'm confused is, I'm supposed to be able to do this from the root monorepo/ directory, and be able to build all backends, or all projects if they have changed.

I've tried to configure the root directory with `npx create-nx-workspace` but I'm told by the nx Discord that this is only for fresh projects.

I've tried `npx add-nx-to-monorepo` but this just gives me an nx.json, nx, nx.bat and a .gitignore. There's no workspaces.conf (deprecated as I mentioned above), no package.json.. what am I supposed to do here to make the root directory nx work with the subdirectories?

Is there actually some way of using `nx init` in a subdirectory then joining this to the workspace in its own parent directory (monorepo/ in my case)?

Appreciate any guidance or links to actual up to date documentation or guides.